# Java var turning back to 0 when displayed on new frame

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

OK so its not a problem within the action method but in when its displayed on the new frame. Here is the new code the displays the count and average score twice, once on the first frame (the correct values) and then on the second (its been set back to 0 for an unknown reason).

```
package testing2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Testing2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private double score;
    protected double totalScore;
    protected double averageScore;
    protected int counter = 0;
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");
    JButton display = new JButton("Display");
    JTextField scoreField = new JTextField("0", 3);
    JTextField commentField = new JTextField(30);
    JLabel explainationLabel = new JLabel("Please Score your overall                 saticfaction with our app");
    JLabel explainationLabel2 = new JLabel("Enter any comments or suggestions");
    JLabel testDisplay = new JLabel();

    public Testing2() {
        super("App Survey");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(explainationLabel);
        add(scoreField);
        add(explainationLabel2);
        add(commentField);
        add(next);
        add(display);
        add(testDisplay);
        next.addActionListener(this);
        display.addActionListener(this);
    }

public Testing2 (String t){
    super(t);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if(source == next) {
        score = Double.parseDouble(scoreField.getText());
        if(score < 11 && score > 0)
        {
                totalScore += score;
                counter ++;
                scoreField.setText("0");
                commentField.setText("");
        }
        else 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a score bettween 1 and 10", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    

    }
    else {
       averageScore = totalScore / counter;
       testDisplay.setText("The average score is: " + averageScore + " out of " + counter + " votes.");
        viewLoginFrame();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Testing2 testFrame = new Testing2();
    final int WIDTH = 375;
    final int HEIGHT = 200;
    testFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    testFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public void viewLoginFrame() {
    secondframe loginFrame = new secondframe();
    final int WIDTH = 300;
    final int HEIGHT = 200;
    loginFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

```
package testing2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class secondframe extends Testing2 {
    JLabel displayScore = new JLabel();
    JLabel displayScore2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel displayCommentCounter = new JLabel();

public secondframe() {
    super("Survey Results");
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(displayScore);
    add(displayScore2);
    add(displayCommentCounter);
    displayScore.setText("The average overall saticfaction");
    displayScore2.setText("score for the day is: " + averageScore);
    displayCommentCounter.setText("The total number of Surveys taken was: "   + counter);

}
```

}

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the math part is not working?

Comment: Are you saying that the `if(score < 11 && score > 0)` block is entered, but the counter is not incremented?  What is `comments` where is it defined? Are you sure that this code is running?  Have you tired to debug it?

Comment: It is supposed to be displayed on another frame after the results button is pressed, with this code its displays 0 for both averageScore and surveyCounter. But if i set surveyCounter = to say 5 (when the var is declared) it will display 5 for surveyCounter

Comment: Time to use your debugger and do some debugging. And in fact you should do this before posting a question here. If still stuck after doing that then post a valid [mcve].

Comment: yes the if block is entered, and the counter is not incremented. comments is a String array defined just under the string comment var. Yes the code is running, and i have tried to debug it and it shows no issues.

Comment: Then I'll wait for your [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) code post (please post it here and not in a link). Good luck!

Comment: `comments is a String array defined just under the string comment` - can not see it!

Comment: I've not gone through all the code, but I see one big glaring red flag immediately -- you have one class extending the other, and this you shouldn't do, and in fact it may be a dangerous thing to do. I'm not sure why you're using inheritance here, and while there are appropriate places to use it, this is not one.

Comment: In fact your use of inheritance is the cause of your downfall. Get rid of it, pass the information from one object to the other, and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to a misuse of inheritance. You're trying to pass information from one object to another, a common problem in programming, and the solution is to do just that, create the two objects and then pass the information where and when needed, either by calling a setter method or passing it into a constructor. You're trying to do this by having the 2nd object extend the first, and that won't work, because the 2nd object is completely unique and separate from the first with its own non-transferable state. Solution: get rid of the misuse of inheritance.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Testing2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private double score;
    protected double totalScore;
    protected double averageScore;
    protected int counter = 0;
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");
    JButton display = new JButton("Display");
    JTextField scoreField = new JTextField("0", 3);
    JTextField commentField = new JTextField(30);
    JLabel explainationLabel = new JLabel(
            "Please Score your overall                 saticfaction with our app");
    JLabel explainationLabel2 = new JLabel("Enter any comments or suggestions");
    JLabel testDisplay = new JLabel();

    public Testing2() {
        super("App Survey");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(explainationLabel);
        add(scoreField);
        add(explainationLabel2);
        add(commentField);
        add(next);
        add(display);
        add(testDisplay);
        next.addActionListener(this);
        display.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public Testing2(String t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == next) {
            score = Double.parseDouble(scoreField.getText());
            if (score < 11 && score > 0) {
                totalScore += score;
                counter++;
                scoreField.setText("0");
                commentField.setText("");
            } else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a score bettween 1 and 10",
                        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        } else {
            averageScore = totalScore / counter;
            testDisplay.setText("The average score is: " + averageScore + " out of " + counter
                    + " votes.");
            viewLoginFrame();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing2 testFrame = new Testing2();
        final int WIDTH = 375;
        final int HEIGHT = 200;
        testFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void viewLoginFrame() {
        // !! SecondFrame2 loginFrame = new SecondFrame2();
        SecondFrame2 loginFrame = new SecondFrame2(this); // !!
        final int WIDTH = 300;
        final int HEIGHT = 200;
        loginFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        loginFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public double getAverageScore() {
        return averageScore;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}

class SecondFrame2 extends JFrame {
    JLabel displayScore = new JLabel();
    JLabel displayScore2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel displayCommentCounter = new JLabel();
    private Testing2 testing2; // set up field if we need it

    // !! accept a Testing2 object in parameter
    public SecondFrame2(Testing2 testing2) {
        super("Survey Results");
        this.testing2 = testing2; // use the parameter to set the reference
        // setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(displayScore);
        add(displayScore2);
        add(displayCommentCounter);
        displayScore.setText("The average overall saticfaction");

        // !! extract the information we need by calling methods on testing2:

        // displayScore2.setText("score for the day is: " + averageScore);
        displayScore2.setText("score for the day is: " + testing2.getAverageScore());
        // displayCommentCounter.setText("The total number of Surveys taken was: " + counter);
        displayCommentCounter.setText("The total number of Surveys taken was: " + testing2.getCounter());

    }
}
```

Note that this code does not correct many other problems in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed that.